# remove all words that are not nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, or proper names. spacy python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I wrote the code below and I want Print out the words in the first 10 sentences, and i want to remove all words that are not nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, or proper names.but I dont know how?  can anyone help me?

```
! pip install wget
import wget
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirkhovy/NLPclass/master/data/moby_dick.txt'
wget.download(url, 'moby_dick.txt')
documents = [line.strip() for line in open('moby_dick.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()]

import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

tokens = [[token.text for token in nlp(sentence)] for sentence in documents[:200]]
pos = [[token.pos_ for token in nlp(sentence)] for sentence in documents[:100]]
pos
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? You don't know how or there is an error somewhere?

Comment: I dont know how, this has not error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is to know which POS symbols are used to represent these entities. Here is the [list from Spacy](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#pos-tagging) documentation. This code will help you with this requirement:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') #you can use other methods
# excluded tags
excluded_tags = {"NOUN", "VERB", "ADJ", "ADV", "ADP", "PROPN"}
document = [line.strip() for line in open('moby_dick.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()]

sentences = document[:10] #first 10 sentences
new_sentences = []
for sentence in sentences:
    new_sentence = []
    for token in nlp(sentence):
        if token.pos_ not in excluded_tags:
            new_sentence.append(token.text)
    new_sentences.append(" ".join(new_sentence))
```

Now, `new_sentences` have the same sentences like before but without any Nouns, verbs, ... etc. You can make sure of that by iterating over `sentences` and `new_sentences` to see the different:

```
for old_sen, new_sen in zip(sentences, new_sentences):
    print("Before:", old_sen)
    print("After:", new_sen)
    print()
Before: Loomings .
After: .

Before: Call me Ishmael .
After: me .

Before: Some years ago -- never mind how long precisely -- having little or no money in my purse , and nothing particular to interest me on shore , I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world .
After: Some -- -- or no my , and nothing to me , I I a and the the .

Before: It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation .
After: It is a I have the and the .

...
...
```